# Modifying displayed content in django-tables2 cells

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm trying to slice strings in django-tables2.

Here's my model:

```
#models.py

class Claim(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here's my view:

```
#views.py

class ClaimsView(tables.SingleTableView):
    table_class = ClaimsTable
    queryset = Claim.objects.all()
    template_name = "portal/claims.html"
```

Here's my table:

```
#tables.py

class ClaimsTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Claim
        fields = ('id', 'product', 'member', 'date_added', 'text')
```

And this is how I render the table in my template file:

```
{# claims.html #}

{% render_table table %}
```

My goal is to display only the first 30 characters of `text` in the table for each claim.

When I was building this table earlier without django-tables2, I did this with `{{ claim.text|slice:":30" }}`.

How can I replicate this in django-tables2?

I looked through the documentation and other posts here but I couldn't figure it out unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the django-tables2 documentation again, I managed to solve this by creating each column separately (instead of using `class Meta`, `model` and `fields`) and then modifying how the column is rendered using `render_foo` method and `value` keyword argument ([link to relevant documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html)).

Here's the modified tables.py file:

```
#tables.py

import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Claim

class ClaimsTable(tables.Table):

    id = tables.Column()
    product = tables.Column()
    member = tables.Column()
    date_added = tables.Column()
    status = tables.Column()
    text = tables.Column()

    def render_text(self, value):
        return str(value[:30] + "...")
```

Is this a good way to do this? Are there better solutions that I should consider?